# Bind SSH client to two different host addresses

Tags: ssh, networking, port-forwarding

I have this port forwarding solution for testing purposes. There is a distant server named *box* and a local machine named *tower*, on two separate networks. *box* is accessible through the internet.

On *tower*, I run the following command:

```
ssh -R 80:localhost:80 box.sleblanc
```

This connects to *box* and setups a socket on port 80 that will access a web service on *tower*, port 80. When a connection is established with *box:80*, I find that it appears to the web service in the logs as coming from *127.0.0.1*. I find this annoying as I cannot reliably distinguish between the connections that are legitimately from my localhost as opposed to those that come from via the proxy.

By setting the `BindAddress` option to something different (e.g. *192.168.0.100*) the connections to the proxy actually show up as that address instead, which solves my problem, but it forces my service to run on a network address other than localhost.

I found that running `curl --interface 127.0.0.2 localhost:80` will produce requests from the IP address `127.0.0.2`, which fulfills my requirement of being able to distinguish between legitimately local requests versus proxied requests, however, when setting `BindAddress` to *127.0.0.2*, SSH can no longer reach *box*, as the *127.0.0.0/8* network is not routeable.

Ultimately, my question is: how can I bind the SSH client to multiple different addresses, so that the client can connect to an Internet host while the remote port redirection will come from an unrouteable address other than *127.0.0.1*? That is, strictly bind connections to the remote forwarded port to the local address *127.0.0.2*?

---

Toying with *socat*, I discovered this solution:

```
% socat TCP4-Listen:1234,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:80,bind=127.0.0.2 &
% ssh -R 80:127.0.0.1:1234 box.sleblanc
```

This sets up a socket on that listens to incoming connections on port 1234 and forwards them to 127.0.0.1:80 by binding to the local address *127.0.0.2*. It works exactly as intended, but I am wondering if there is a way to streamline this into the SSH command.

Comment: You would need `ssh` to bind on a specified interface when creating the local sockets for `-R`, but I see no way to specify this in `man ssh`. So if you want to do this with `ssh` only, you'll likely have to modify the code to provide this option (and submit a patch). You can also connect the remote box to your local box with a different kind of tunnel which preserves IP addresses.

Comment: On a Linux system, this hack (on tower) will "fix" ssh: `iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.2 -j SNAT --to-source 127.0.0.2`

Comment: @A.B, interesting. This rewrites packets addressed to 127.0.0.2 so that they show up as coming from 127.0.0.2 instead of 127.0.0.1, is that so?

Comment: yes. even tested it (using.. socat with -d -d of course) before commenting. But your question doesn't specify the OS

Comment: GNU plus Linux.